# Incrementing Through URLs and Downloading

Tags: browser, download, automation, html

I would just like a simple browser automation that increments one number in a URL and downloads the information from that place. For example, if the address looks like this:

www.test.com/something/part1_0.jpg

How could I increment the '1' and download the file from each successive web page?

Thanks

P.S. I'm using OS X 10.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a ruby solution using [open-uri](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html):

```
require 'open-uri'

(1..100).each do |num|                                          
  File.open("part#{num}_0.jpg", 'wb') do |f|
    f.write open("www.test.com/something/part#{num}_0.jpg").read 
  end
end
```

This snippet A) creates a range of numbers; B) iterates over the range of numbers; C) opens an image file in binary mode and interpolates the current number into the file name; and D) reads the image from the URL and writes it.

But the easiest way would probably be to use curl from your command line:

```
curl -O www.test.com/something/part[1-100]_0.jpg
```

Depending on the number of webpages that you need to access, modify the numbers in brackets accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfectly, even though I had no previous experience of ruby! I was also able to modify it to my own needs. You saved me a hell of a lot of time!

Comment: Oh, and thanks for the command line solution, shame I didn't see it before.