# How to download images from a non-public web folder?

Tags: image, download, automation, directory

I'm looking for a way to download images off websites and put them all in a zip, folder on a web  server, or folder on a local computer. The folder where the images are stored isn't public but the URL of the images are easy to predict.  For example,

```
example.com/images/99.png
example.com/images/100.png
example.com/images/101.png
example.com/images/102.png
```

etc.
Though if I just go to   example.com/images/ it displays a blank page, not an image list.

What would be a good way to go about doing this?

Comment: Do you have to authenticate to access the URLs?

Comment: No, at least not that I can tell. URLs look public to me.

Comment: Check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28787295/incrementing-through-urls-and-downloading/28788161#28788161).  If you're partial to ruby, that answer + the [rubyzip](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip) gem should point you in the right direction.  `curl` is a good option as well.